# Windows Server AppFabric Monitoring for ASP.NET Web API Services

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, appfabric

I have searched high and low for an answer to this question, so I'm now turning to this community for an answer to the following question:

Is it at all possible to enable Windows Server AppFabric Monitoring for an ASP.NET Web API (not WCF) RESTful Service using .NET 4.5 RC?

Answer (score 0):

Look at http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a685f193-ed1e-4ad4-938f-f0bd8212d53d

Should help you.